# General question on $\epsilon$ and choice of $a$ and $b$

Tags: calculus, limits

Well I do have a small understanding issue here.

If you say that for every  $\epsilon > 0$ there are two values $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a \neq b$ such that $ a - b  < \epsilon$. Thats not a problem there.

But when you say that there are two fixed values $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x-y < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. How does this not imply that $x = y$ ?

I mean in the upper case you can choose $a = b+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ or something. But in the second case you already got two fixed values which are so close together that the difference is smaller than every $\epsilon > 0$. We had that in class and the lecturer told as it does not necessary mean that $x = y$.

Comment: Yes. I was already thinking about that but thats how we did it in class.

Answer (score 3):

If, for instance, $x=0$ and $y=1$, then it is true that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, $x-y<\varepsilon$. However, $x\neq y$.

You would be right if the condition was $|x-y|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Okay I see. What would be your answer if $x > y$ ?

Comment: @Arjihad If $x>y$, then the assertion “for every $\varepsilon>0$, $x-y<\varepsilon$” is false.

Comment: Okay. Lets say we have $x > y$ such that $x-y < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. Does this imply that $x = y$ ?

Comment: @Arjihad Yes, because if you havve two assertions $P$ and $Q$, and $P$ is false, then $P\implies Q$, no matter what $Q$ is.

Comment: @Arjihad you may be thinking of requiring $x \geq y$